# can't connect db with xampp

Tags: php, database, xampp

in dbconect

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo " can't connect : " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;   
}
?>
```

and in dbconfig

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', "localhost");
define('DB_USER', "root");
define('DB_PASS', "");
define('DB_NAME', "carwash");
define('DB_PREFIX', "carwash_");
?>
```

and output

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (42000/1049): Unknown database 'carwash' in C:\xampp\htdocs\carwash\includes\dbconnect.php on line 2
can't connect : Unknown database 'carwash'
```

I don't know what's wrong or what's happened, it happen only today but the day pass it didn't happen

Comment: It says that you don't have a database called **carwash** !. may be you removed OR deleted it ?

Comment: after creating database ,have you used `use carwash` ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a database named `carwash`.

Xampp comes with phpmyadmin,have a look for the databases you have there.